# How to partially render HTML that has escaped elements

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

Say I've got the following string:

```
var s = '<a href="https://cnn.com?x=&lt;svg/onload=alert(123)&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;" target="_blank">cnn</a>'
```

Whether I use `innerHTML` from vanilla JS or `.html(...)` in jQuery, if I render the string, it becomes the following HTML:

```
<a href="https://cnn.com?x=<svg/onload=alert(123)></svg>" target="_blank">
    cnn
</a>
```

Assuming this is one part of a much larger HTML string, where the same thing applies in many places, how could I prevent the encoded elements `&lt;` and `&gt;` from being turned back into HTML, but render the rest? Including the literal `<` and `>` tags?

Comment: You need to URIEncode those on the server

Comment: When you say URIEncode, you mean replace with `%3C` and `%3E` respectively? In this case it's in an `href`, but what about scenarios like `document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "<p data-test='&amp;'>Test</p>"`? This renders with `data-test="&"`.

Comment: What can I say. Don't put HTML in URLs. What is the usecase here? Can't you pass the data and construct the HTML or use Ajax?

Comment: The use case was a user "potentially" storing XSS in an "add a link" functionality within a rich-text-editor. I think the odds of this coming back to bite us is pretty small, and my "fix" was already what you suggested & using percent-style encoding instead (though it may not work for all scenarios). Just thought this question was potentially interesting; using the console directly it converts `&amp;` back to `&`, so it may actually be impossible to store them as values in HTML.

Comment: There is certainly potential. I saw this when a site rendered "`whatever was in the query` not found"